# Menu inflating issue in Multiple fragment hierarchy

Tags: android, menu, android-viewpager, fragment, toolbar

[image]

Facing issue while inflating different Menu in different fragment.

My application hierarchy is like:
BottomNavigationView --> Fragments(4) ---> Tab+ViewPager --> Fragments(3)

Each fragment contains ViewPager and ViewPager contains multiple fragments.

Please see the attached image for more clarity.

**Issue**: It's keep on adding new menu, or sometimes carry previous screen menu.

I have tried using "menu.clear()", "getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();"

Comment: And what is the problem ? Describe it

Comment: @MishaAkopov Thank You!. It's keep on adding new menu. If I use menu.clear(), sometimes will carry previous screen menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `ViewPager`, it means that if you go to `i`th position, fragments that are on position `i-1` and `i+1` will also be created. So their **onCreateOptionsMenu** will be called and even if you call menu.clear() it will not work properly.

Solution is to change menu in container Fragment/Activity of **ViewPager** , in following way. Add ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener to **ViewPager** and in **onPageSelected(int position)** method change menu yourself:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            int menuResourceId = getMenuResourceByPosition(position); 
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(menuResourceId, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

create method `getMenuResourceByPosition` that will give you proper menu resource id by `ViewPager`'s selected position.

Comment: I have used your code, and somehow able to load relevant menu but menu items immediately disappears on changing tab.

Comment: From BottomNavigation menu  Tab ? Maybe you have somewhere `menu.clear()` left ? Also set menu setting login on upper level  : on tab selection.

Comment: I have used **setMenuVisibility(false)**, it was creating issue.